# Printing an Array into String

Tags: java, arrays

For an Assignment I have to create a Five in a Row Game with a print Method. So basically my Idea is that the Method goes through the whole two dimensional Array and everytime there is a 0 it adds a "-"  to the String row instead. When there is 1 or 2 it adds the Number. When the [j] Array is finished it prints the whole row and initializes the row anew. Terminal is another Class which was given to us to print everything in the Class.

The Problem is the whole Method doesn't print anything at all and I don't know where the Problem could be.

```
public static void print() {
    String row = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == 0) {
                row += "-";
            } else  {
                row += (char) (board[i][j]);
            }
            if (j == board[i].length) {
               Terminal.printLine(row);
               row = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Terminal`?  Also note that since `j < board[i].length`, it will never be equal to it, move your print to after the inside for loop

Comment: `if(j == board[i].length)` should be `if(j == board[i].length - 1)`. Or, as phflack said, move it after the inner for loop.

Comment: @phflack Terminal is a Class provided the University to print or read things in the Class. We need to use it to print it (Not allowed to use System.out.print etc)

Comment: @phflack Ok thx that did do the trick. Didn't think that that was the Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because variable j will never be equal as length of board[i].

Your for loop i is only iterate from 0, 1, 2, ..., board.length - 1.

Same with your loop j. It is only iterate from 0, 1, 2, ..., board[i].length - 1

Except if you are using `j <= board[i].length`, but it probably will throw IndexOutOfRangeException.

Your code should be like this.

```
public static void print() {
    String row = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == 0) {
                row += "-";
            } else  {
                row += (char) (board[i][j]);
            }
            if (j == board[i].length - 1) {
               Terminal.printLine(row);
               row = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other peoples in this question attempt to help you with your existent code. Take some time to discover Java 8 Streams API, your problems is pretty simple to solve with it !

```
String[][] board = {{"a", "a", "a"}, {"b", "c", "d"}, {"e", "f", "g"}};

Arrays.stream(board).map(r -> String.join("-", r)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

### Step by step:

1. `Arrays.stream(board)` transform your board array to a stream of `String[]`.
2. `.map(r -> String.join("-", r))` map all your `String[]` to `String` where each elements are joined by "-"
3. `.forEach(System.out::println)` wrote it directly on the console (you could use `Terminal::printLine` in your case if you prefer here).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i suggest you to use `StringBuilder` append method instead of `String` concatenation.
The program will never enter in this if statement, because j will never be equal to board[i].length.

```
if (j == board[i].length) {
    Terminal.printLine(row);
    row = "";
}
```

Instead you can compare j to board[i].length - 1 but this is just useless. You can move the Terminal.printLine(row) outside of the inner for loop.

I will refactor the code for you:

```
public static void print() {
    StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == 0) {
                row.append("-");
            } else  {
                row.append((char) (board[i][j]));
            }
        }
        Terminal.printLine(row.toString());
        row = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
```

If the `StringBuilder` is inefficient in this case you can still use String but my opinion is that `StringBuilder` is always better.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `if (j == board[i].length)` block with `if (j == board[i].length - 1)`. Since your for loops continues until `board[i].length`, it will never enter your if statement.

Additionally, if your array is an integer array and cast an integer to char using `(char) (board[i][j])`, you will get the ASCII value with value 1, which will not be equal to '1', '2', etc. If that's the case, use `(char)(board[i][j] + '0')`.